# Formatting paragraph

Tags: formatting

I do not understand what happens with my paragraph. I have a few math expressions that I put between dollar signs, but the whole expression is bleeding out of the page:

```
\input{preamble.tex}

\begin{document}

\title{Problem 6: Förhållande mellan triangel areor}
%http://www.forkosh.com/latex/ltx-138.html, hanterar headings
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE \bf Problem 6: Förhållande mellan triangel areor}\\
\small \today \\ 
\end{center}
\vspace{0.2in}
%där tar min title import slut


 \section{Problembeskrivning:}

 I triangel \triangle $ABC$ är $D$ den punkt på sidan $AB$ för vilken $|BD|=4|AD|$, och $E$ är den punkt på sidan $BC$ för vilken $|CE|=4|BE|$. 
 Låt F vara skärningspunkten mellan DE och medianen från B. Sätt $\overrightarrow{u}=\overline{AB}$ och $\overrightarrow{v}=\overline{AC}$. Uttryck $\overline{BE}$ och $\overline{BF}$ i $\overrightarrow{u}$ och $\overrightarrow{v}$. Visa också att triangel \triangle $BEF$ alltid upptar samma proportion av \triangel $ABC$, och ange förhållande mellan trianglarnas areor.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess you want to move the `\triangle`s into math environments, i.e. `$\triangle ABC$` instead of `\triangle $ABC$` (twice) and `$\triangle BEF$` instead of `\triangle $BEF$`.

Comment: And you want to use `\triangle` instead of `\triangel`.

Comment: Also, please post what you defined in preamble.tex

Comment: you would have had an error message on the `\triangle` If you are asking about an error please show the full text of the error message, not the output, it is usually not worth looking at the output after any Tex error, TeX's error recovery does not try to make sensible output, just to get in to a state that it can process more document to check for more errors.